# Coding Gravity in Pygame (Impractical Python Projects)

Tags: python, pygame, gravity

I am stuck on a particular project - Chapter 13 (Simulating an Alien Volcano) - of Lee Vaughan's Impractical Python Projects book.

In it, we are supposed to simulate the volcano on Io, Jupiter's satellite. The code can be found [here](https://github.com/rlvaugh/Impractical_Python_Projects/blob/master/Chapter_13/practice_45.py):

My query specifically:

I understand that the displacement of the particles are first calculated by:

```
radians = math.radians(orient)
self.dx = self.vel * math.cos(radians)
self.dy = -self.vel * math.sin(radians) # negative as y increases down
```

and then gravity is added to the Y-axis thus:

```
self.dy += Particle.GRAVITY
pg.draw.line(self.background, self.color, (self.x, self.y), (self.x + self.dx, self.y + self.dy))
self.x += self.dx
self.y += self.dy
```

Question I have is this: In all of the above, at a certain point, the force of gravity would have to be over-powering enough such that the particle starts coming down instead of going up; however, the self.dy is only a function of two constants (the initial velocity, gravity). So it should continue to go in a straight line. For example, for a particle being ejected at a certain angel (say, z):

```
self.dy = self.vel*math.sin(z) + particle.GRAVITY
```

Here,

1. self.vel is fixed
2. z is fixed for each particle type
3. GRAVITY is fixed for each particle type

So, 'dy' will stay the same across any given period of time. Yet, the simulation shows a projectile motion...HOW?

Comment: Gravity gets added to `dy` at every time step.  So, the gravity keeps getting larger and larger.  Acceleration is the second derivative, and so modifies velocity at each step, which then modifies position.

Comment: Thanks, got it. I got confused by line 50. I had thought the update function was dy + gravity in subsequent updates, but I see now that it's dy += gravity only (essentially over-writing line 50 after the very first cycle. 

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gravity is not added to `self.y`, but to `self.dy`. This happens in every frame. Therefore, the amount of `self.dy` increases a little in each frame and the position of the object changes a little more in each frame. This causes an accelerated movement and an increasing speed of fall.